# Invoking SQL Adapter from Java

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Worklight Version 6.2

The adapters are deployed, and server is up.

I'm using the below code to invoke a SQL procedure:

```
 DataAccessService service = WorklightBundles.getInstance().getDataAccessService();
ProcedureQName procedureQname = new ProcedureQName("EAttendanceSQLAdapter", "checkDomain");
String paramArray = "['"+userName+"']";
System.out.println("paramArray : "+ paramArray);
logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>>after procedureQname>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
InvocationResult result = service.invokeProcedure(procedureQname,paramArray);
com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject resultJsonObject = result.toJSON();
```

Its throwing me

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at this line "  DataAccessService service = WorklightBundles.getInstance().getDataAccessService();"

Kindly advice. But the same set of code has worked for me in a different project.

Thanks

Comment: You are likely using a different java version? or perhaps the eclipse is not running/using the same JRE?

Comment: Hi Idan, we are using Java Version : 1.7 for both the projects.

Comment: Provide the full log with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Something is not right IMO with the following line...
`String paramArray = "['"+userName+"']";`

Here's a working example:

```
import com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject;
import com.worklight.server.bundle.api.WorklightBundles;
import com.worklight.server.integration.api.DataAccessService;
import com.worklight.server.integration.api.InvocationResult;
import com.worklight.server.integration.api.ProcedureQName;

public void callProcedure() {
    DataAccessService service = WorklightBundles.getInstance().getDataAccessService();
    String paramArray = "['param1', 'param2', 'param3']";
    ProcedureQName procedureQName = new ProcedureQName("adapterName",
"procedureName");
    InvocationResult result = service.invokeProcedure(procedureQName,paramArray);
    JSONObject jsonObject = result.toJSON();
    String value = (String)jsonObject.get("key");
}
```